# MVC4 how to make file upload required validation

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, requiredfieldvalidator

any one have been implemented of validation required attribute for jquery file upload then please help me on it.

How should be possible to make required attribute?

Do i need to make custom validation?

if any one have example please help me on it.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Suppose if your form looks like,

```
@(Html.BeginForm("Home","Upload",FormMethod.Post,new{id="form1",enctype="multipart/form-data"))
{
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
<input type="submit" value="upload" onclick="return uploadFile();"/>
}
```

in javascript,

```
function uploadFile()
{
var filename=$('#file').val();
if(filename=='')
{
//Show error message or alert('please choose file');
return false;
}
else
{
return true;
}
}
```

you can also restrict user to upload only particular type of files like JPEG,jpg,gif etc.

```
var Re = /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.jpeg|.JPEG|.jpg|.gif|.GIF| .png|.PNG)$/;            
if (Re.test(filename) == false) {
 alert('Please select valid Image');
 return false;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do not want message using alert, i want to use mvc4 razor engine validation